# Referencing template in Azure Templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM Template stored in Azure Templates.

Is there a way to reference this template from script (either in Azure Cloud Shell or PowerShell/CLI on local machine)? Right now it seems the only way to deploy the template is through the Azure portal UI.

**Update**

I wanted to clarify what I am asking. I am asking specifically about `Azure Templates (Preview)` service. It seems that once you store a template in Templates service the only way to access it is through the Azure portal.

For example, let's say I am creating a VM in Azure portal. I can save the ARM template to Templates service as shown in the images below.

You can click on `Download Template and parameters` link, on next page click on `Add to library` to save the template to Templates service (Templates service can be found in Azure portal through All Service > filter for "Templates").

I was doing the course on edX.org: [Automating Azure Workloads](https://www.edx.org/course/automating-azure-workloads-0) and it was talking about this service, that's why I became interested in this service.

[image: Create VM pane]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this, or did you just publish to an external source?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a template with every possible mean you mention. Not only the portal UI.

There is documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy) - section `Deploy a template from external reosurce` (also explains how to deploy from a `private` resource using SAS:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup `
  -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json `
  -storageAccountType Standard_GRS
```

The referenced documentation also provides sample for use with [Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy).

Comment: Thanks. But it seems there is no way to deploy from Azure Templates. I guess it's not a particularly useful service.

Comment: Can you elaborate and be more concrete in your question.  ARM is particularly the most useful service for service automation.

Comment: Yes, ARM is indeed great. However, I am talking specifically about `Azure Templates (Preview)` service where you can store ARM templates. But once you store the template, it seems the only way to access it is through Azure portal.